# Finding maximum value of $\frac{\cos x-\cos y}{x-y}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, maxima-minima

Title says it all. I was thinking of using the fact that

$$\lim_{x\to y}\frac{\cos x-\cos y}{x-y}=-\sin y\in [-1,1]$$

So, I think maximum value should not exceed $1$. But that is just heuristics and I cannot proceed further.

Comment: You don't even need the limit, just the mean value theorem. $\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}=f'(z)$ for some $z$ between $x$ and $y.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, ok thanks. Mean value theorem didn't click me. Please post it as an answer.

Comment: But are you interested in maximum or supremum? Because the latter is 1 as basically shown above, but the former doesn't exist.

Comment: @RomanHric, can you elaborate your claim? The argument in the first comment just shows that $1$ is an upper bound of the image of this function. It doesn't show that $1$ is supremum, as far as I understand.

Comment: If you fix eg. $y= -\pi / 2$ then you can get as close to 1 as you want by chosing $x$ close to $y$ using the Mean Value Theorem as suggested by Thomas Andrews since $z$ then has to be also close to $y= -\pi / 2$.

Comment: @RomanHric And that value $1$ will never be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the discussion in the comments under the question.

Let us define
$$
S := \left\{ \frac{\cos x - \cos y}{x - y}; \ x,y \in \mathbb R, x \neq y \right\}.
$$
We claim that $\sup S = 1$ but it's not attained, i.e. $\max S$ doesn't exist.

First, let us realize that $1$ is an upper bound of S:
for $x \neq y$ we get by Lagrange that $\cos x - \cos y = - \sin z \cdot(x - y)$ for some $z$ strictly in between $x$ and $y$. From this we  easily get an upper bound $1$ for the set $S$.

Now, we can get as close to $1$ as we wish. First, fix $y := -\pi/2$ then we have $\frac{\cos x - \cos y}{x - y}=- \sin z \in  [-\sin x,-\sin y] = [-\sin x,1]$, at least for $x$ not far from $-\pi/2$. Now just choose $x$ as close to $-\pi/2$ as you wish.
This proves  $\sup S = 1$.

Now we show that $1$ is never attained. It suffices to realize that $\cos x - \cos y < x - y$ for $x>y$. One way to see this is via the definition of the cosine function on the unit circle (just make a picture).

But let's take a ''more analytical'' approach. To see that the function $x - \cos x$ is strictly increasing just realize that its derivative is $1 + \sin x$ which is strictly positive with the exception of the points $x = -\pi/2 + 2k\pi$. And from this we have $y - \cos y < x - \cos x$ for $y<x$ which finishes the proof.